# MongoDB find query with $and $or and $nearSphere in php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

After quite some trying out and web research I go crazy with this query. I want to build a query for 'Clubs' around a geo point (distance max 500 meters) in php on MongoDB.
But when I run query it ignores the distance limit and shows all clubs in database BUT sorted by distance.

Here is my dataset (2dsphere index geoLoc):

```
{"_id":ObjectId("547c649e30afe32c23000048"),"name":"Club Ritzz","category":"Club","category_list":[{"id":"191478144212980","name":"Night Club"}],"location":{"city":"Mannheim"},"geoLoc":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.473665839156,49.484065272756]}}
{"_id":ObjectId("547c649f30afe32c2300004a"),"name":"Das Zimmer Mannheim","category":"Club","category_list":[{"id":"191478144212980","name":"Night Club"}],"geoLoc":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.4709362941178,49.487260552592]}}
{"_id":ObjectId("547c64ab30afe32c23000063"),"name":"Nationaltheater Mannheim","category":"Arts/entertainment/nightlife","category_list":[{"id":"173883042668223","name":"Theatre"}],"geoLoc":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.4776534992592,49.48782606969]}}
{"_id":ObjectId("547c64a130afe32c2300004f"),"name":"SOHO Bar Club Lounge","category":"Club","category_list":[{"id":"191478144212980","name":"Night Club"},{"id":"164049010316507","name":"Gastropub"}],"geoLoc":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.4630844501277,49.49385193591]}}
{"_id":ObjectId("547c64a730afe32c2300005a"),"name":"Loft Club","category":"Club","category_list":[{"id":"191478144212980","name":"Night Club"},{"id":"176139629103647","name":"Dance Club"}],"geoLoc":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.4296300196465,49.484211928258]}}
```

And here my php code (updated Dec-2):

```
$qry = $pub->find(  
  array( '$and' => 
    array(
      array( 'geoLoc' => 
        array('$nearSphere' =>
          array('$geometry' => 
            array('type'=>'Point',
              'coordinates'=>
              array(
                floatval($sLon), floatval($sLat)
              )
            ),
            'maxDistance' => 500
          )
        )
      ),
      array( '$or' =>
        array(
          array( 'name' => new MongoRegex("/.*club/i")),
          array( 'name' => new MongoRegex("/.*zimm/i"))
        )
      ),
      array('$or' => 
        array(
          array('category_list.name' => 'Night Club'), 
          array('category_list.name' => 'Dance Club'), 
          array('category' => 'Club')
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  array('id' => 1, 'name' => 1, '_id' => 0)
);
```

Anyone know why the results are not limited to the specified `maxDistance`?

Comment: Strangly, if I am using an ODM wrapper like mongoQM, the distance search works fine...

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue on StackOverflow which outlines that one has to use radians for the maxDistance parameter.

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/nearsphere-returns-too-many-data-what-am-i-missing-am-i-wrong-is-it-a-bug-d

Also it is probably helpful if you'd test the query in mongo shell without using the PHP APIs first (just to see if the query is generally working and append '.explain()' to it to see what generally happens inside DB).

Comment: Thanks for looking it up! Though, I am quite convinced that maxDistance should be provided as "meters" not radians in case you use a geoJSON field as I am doing.